# Hollow inverted pentagon

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I am trying to make a hollow ( transparent on the inside ) inverted pentagon like this:

[Inverted Pentagon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v85df.png)

I have attempted to do this using the following css:

```
.pentagon {

  border: solid 86px #E44126;
  border-bottom: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  position: absolute;

}

.pentagon:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right bottom,  transparent 50%, #E44126 50%,);
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, transparent 50%, #E44126 50%);

}
.pentagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right bottom, transparent 50%, #E44126 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(to left bottom, transparent 50%, #E44126 50%);
}
```

But I just can figure it out. I thought about using clip-path but there is no browser support for IE.

Comment: please provide your html or a fiddle.

Comment: This is my html:
<div>
                  <div class="pentagon"></div>
                </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a go at it but using a rotation instead. Values can be tweaked for width/height/border size. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KWqEqL

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}


.pentagon {
  border: solid 5px #E44126;
  border-bottom: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}

.pentagon:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 65%;
  height: 65%;
  border: 5px solid #E44126;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-top: 0;
  border-left: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container"><div class="pentagon"></div></div>
```